# Crispy Forms: Is there a way to use crispy forms to render a completly readonly form view?

Tags: django, forms, django-crispy-forms

I started to use django, python and django-crispy-forms some weeks ago. I have spent a lot of time finding a way to reuse the form layout to render a completely readonly view.

Thinking on the DRY principle, it have not much sense to render a form with crispy and write the same layout by hand just to show the user input, by example, in a confirm wizard step, or as simple detail view.

Is there a way to do this, replacing all `<input>` elements by `<span>` or `<p>` elements?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like that? :

```
class CommonFormHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CommonFormHelper, self).__init__()
        self.disable_csrf = True
        self.form_tag = False


class CommonModelFormWithHelper(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommonModelFormWithHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.base_fields['some_field'].widget = forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'disabled': True})
        self.helper = CommonFormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('some_field')
        )


class HumanSignForm(CommonModelFormWithHelper):
    class Meta:
        model = HumanSign


class HumanDescriptionForm(CommonModelFormWithHelper):
    class Meta:
        model = HumanDescription
```